Why and how does merge reorder the rows?
Here are 15 ways of preventing the rows of a dataframe to get all scrambled up when using merge. But none of the answers seems to address the fundamental mystery of why simply calling merge would change the order of the rows in the first place and what is the order it comes up with. The help page of merge doesn't mention it either. I would be very happy if someone here could explain this to me. I mean: who would want to solve a problem if instead you can just understand it?

You can merge faster if you can avoid duplicate look ups. If you group data by common values, you have to move less data around in memory. It's just more efficient. So the inner R function that does the merging does some sorting of data. See
https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0aaca0906661f4d19f9f1abdb5310eef3c46ff9e/src/main/util.c#L715. Note it's not actually sorting the values themselves, it's sorting the indexes in which the values appear in the first table.
